Is it possible to simulate a CRT tv?
With technology quickly moving on, and old tech being left in the past. It's hard to find CRT TV's large enough to play Light gun games without breaking your back. My question: Is it possible to create a program to simulate the way a CRT TV works?

An lcd screen has processing that takes time, thats where the delay comes from. One way to achieve what you want (but not what you ask for) is to patch the game to tolerate screen delay

If you have ever seen the bright dot of an oscilloscope moving left to right (set to a slow sweep) then that's what is actually taking place on a CRT. That bright dot is very easy to pick out with a simple detector circuit. Optics and baffling allows the light gun to only "see" a small image spot where pointed from the right distance away. So it provides an "on" or "off" signal that is monitored for time as the CRT dot sweeps left to right and down. Software knows the timing, so it knows where it points if there is a detection made.

Sounds like you need a CRT projector.

Probably not.
The CRT electron beam excites the phosphor dot on the back of the glass so that there was a step change in light level. The light gun sensor would monitor the light level and differentiate it (possibly just an inline capacitor coupling in the signal path) so that a sudden change in light level gave a pulse. The game logic would check where in the raster scan this occurred and if this was acceptably close to the target position.
The LCD and LED screens hold the pixels for each frame so you don't get the pixel by pixel refresh.
I was never a gamer so there may be other techniques that I'm not aware of.

After some comments ...
One possible way to do it with flat panel TV / monitor would be to strobe a circle in the target area - say 5 or 10 pixel diameter - and toggle it on and off on alternate scans. There are a couple of problems:

The strobe rate would have to match the refresh rate of the monitor. The software would have to read that from the hardware somehow and synchronise with it. I'm not sure if this is possible.
It might be a way to design a game for modern hardware but it won't work on retro games.
You couldn't "track" the gun's aim and move a crosshair (or whatever) around the screen as you would only be blinking the target area.


If one could run the video out through some sort of software that then could tell the "newer" tv to then pulse or flash when needed for tracking on screen. Would something like that work?

I don't think so. There is nothing in the video signal to tell an outboard converter that any particular area is blinking or is the targe. They're really relying on the CRT causing every non-black point on the screen to blink on every raster scan. It was a clever use of the technology.
I recommend the Technology Connections channel on YouTube. The Lines of Light: How Analog Television Works would be a good place to start.

Thank you for the more in-depth on the CRT side of it. You have a much better understanding of it then I could find. I can see why this would not work on a "normal" tv. Would you need to be able to increase brightness of the target pixels in that area? If one could run the video out through some sort of software that then could tell the "newer" tv to then pulse or flash when needed for tracking on screen. Would something like that work?

The video generation of the pixels and the raster display on a CRT are inextricably linked. This gives rise to the term ‘chasing the beam’. Thus it was reasonably simple for the hardware on the game machine to determine what pixels were active when the pulse arrived from the light gun. Not so with fully digital video. Whilst you could make an area flash, that wouldn’t convey any positional information as the pixel generation is detached time wise from the display. Maybe if you could project a laser in a raster onto the lcd and the panel could reflect enough energy for the light gun to detect?

See the update.

Synchronizing to the refresh is easy.
